# How can you catch a "permission denied" error when using fopen in PHP without using try/catch?

Tags: php, error-handling, fopen, permission-denied

I just received an error report for [one of my scripts](https://github.com/tslocum/TinyIB%E2%80%8E) regarding a permission denied error when the script tries to open a new file using 'w' (writing) mode.  Here's the relevant function:

```
function writePage($filename, $contents) {
    $tempfile = tempnam('res/', TINYIB_BOARD . 'tmp'); /* Create the temporary file */
    $fp = fopen($tempfile, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $contents);
    fclose($fp);
    /* If we aren't able to use the rename function, try the alternate method */
    if (!@rename($tempfile, $filename)) {
        copy($tempfile, $filename);
        unlink($tempfile);
    }

    chmod($filename, 0664); /* it was created 0600 */
}
```

You can see the third line is where I am using fopen.  I would like to catch permission denied errors and handle them myself rather than print an error message.  I realize this is very easy using a try/catch block, but portability is a large selling point for my script.  I can't sacrifice compatibility with PHP 4 to handle an error.  Please help me catch a permission error without printing any errors/warnings.

Comment: While I'm for compatibility, why on earth are you trying to maintain PHP 4 support?

Comment: Before I was able to afford paid hosting I migrated between many free hosts.  In that time I learned that many of these hosts aren't exactly in a hurry to provide PHP 5 to their users.  When writing the script one of my goals was to fully support such a host.  It will even operate using a flat file database.  Posts can be saved to the file system rather than using MySQL/SQLite if absolutely necessary.  So all that is required for the script is PHP 4 and the GD library.  This is overkill from the perspective of paid hosting, sure, but it's necessary in order to support virtually any free host.

Comment: Well, I applaud your commitment to backwards compatibility. As a recommendation, perhaps consider forking your project into a pre/post 5.3 branches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can prevent the error by using this solution. Just add an extra check after `tempnam` line

```
$tempfile = tempnam('res/', TINYIB_BOARD . 'tmp'); 

# Since we get the actual file name we can check to see if it is writable or not
if (!is_writable($tempfile)) {
    # your logic to log the errors

    return;
}

/* Create the temporary file */
$fp = fopen($tempfile, 'w');
```